# How to force 4 digits in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a really long truth table and the binary column is showing up like this:

```
A   +   B   =   S   BINARY
0   +   0   =   0   0
0   +   1   =   1   1
0   +   2   =   2   10
0   +   3   =   3   11
0   +   4   =   4   100
0   +   5   =   5   101
0   +   6   =   6   110
0   +   7   =   7   111
0   +   8   =   8   1000
0   +   9   =   9   1001
0   +   10  =   10  1010
0   +   11  =   11  1011
0   +   12  =   12  1100
0   +   13  =   13  1101
0   +   14  =   14  1110
0   +   15  =   15  1111
```

Where the BINARY column `=DEC2BIN(S)`

I need to force the Binary values to have 4 digits all the time. So `0 = 0000`, `3 = 0011`, etc. How do I do this in excel?

**Solution:
`=DEC2BIN(S,6)`**

Comment: Format as text to keep the leading zeros

Comment: Can you post a sample excel sheet (e.g. dropbox) showing the problem?

Comment: If your solution is an answer to your question, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than filling column S with:

=A1 + B1

to see 1 thru 15, use:

=DEC2BIN(A1+B1,4)  to keep the leading zeros in 4-digit-binary format.

Answer (score 3):

1. Highlight binary cells
2. Right-click, select "Format Cells..."
3. Number tab, select "Custom"
4. Enter `0000` into the Type text box.
5. Click OK.

Comment: Nothing :(. It stays the same

Comment: You know what though, it worked in a non formula cell. So I just cut and pasted the values as values then applied the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Another, not the best way, but should work:
`=RIGHT("0000"&DEC2BIN(S),4)`

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is correct

```
=DEC2BIN(A1,4)
```

This will show cell A1 in binary 4 digit format regardless of the value .

In the Spanish Excel version you use a semi colon like so .

```
=DEC.A.BIN(J6;7)
```